# Is it possible to send HTTP requests with cookie from other sites appended, using Firefox/Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

So basically I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to send HTTP requests using extensions while append a self-defined `cookie` header? I know neither `fetch` nor `XMLHttpRequest` will allow cookie to be appended. Is there any other API that can be used to send requests that allow `cookie` be appended?
2. Is it possible to obtain cookies of another domain stored by the browser, and append this cookie to the request in the previous questions?

Comment: 1) Yes, see examples for chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders. 2) Yes, see the documentation/examples for chrome.cookies API.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks, but what I want is to issue a request in the extension, using APIs such as ```fetch```, other than modifying a request issued by the browser and intercepted by the addon.

Comment: I know. My comment above is exactly about this use case.

Comment: @wOxxOm, could you be more specific please? I know if I use ```fetch``` or ```XMLHttpRequest```, they won't allow me to append self-defined ```cookie``` headers. I am not sure how does onBeforeSendHeaders are related to my 1st question. Could you let me know what APIs I will use to initiate such request? Thank you!

Comment: Add a listener and use the standard fetch/xhr, then in the listener modify the headers. There should be examples around, here's [one from greasemonkey](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/master/src/bg/on-user-script-xhr.js).

Comment: Yes! I forgot the ```fetch``` in the extension is also subject to the extension itself, kind of like a recursive function call. Thank you I'll give it a try.